# Finding boundary between two different groups of points

Tags: python

I have a dataset with premises and their location in lat/lon points. Not all the premises are the same. Some premises are offices and other premises are houses. I am trying to find the best way to create polygons that cover as many premises that are houses while covering the least amount of offices. For simplicity, in this question we can consider 1 house to be worth the same as 1 office.

I currently have a good working solution by creating a grid of polygons on top of all the premises and calculating how many houses and how many offices are in each cell. Then just grouping the cells that cover more houses than offices into bigger shapes.

However, I am wondering if there is any algorithm that can create a boundary line between the two types of premises?

There is no need to divide the premises into 2 different areas, this division can be in many different smaller areas, positive areas within a bigger negative zone etc.

There has to be a better, smarter way to do this. It feels like my current approach is just brute force.

Any ideas?

I am currently running my approach with Python using GeoPandas and Shapely files.

Comment: do you mean Delaunay / Thiessen polygons?

Comment: You do not mention which software you are using so I did not include links to different tools.  The general workflow might be...Create a point density layer using just the house data. Something like houses per hectare.  Create a point density layer using just the office data.  Subtract office from house.  Any pixel with a 0 value has the same density of house to office.  Pick some threshold value you like, reclassify.  Convert the reclassification to polygon if you need to.

Comment: @DPSSpatial Yes voronoi regions are something that i have explored, but in this case, i dont want to create a voronoi region for every premise. I would like to create multiple regions that enclose the most amount of houses and the minimum amount of offices. I guess i could create a voronoi region for every premise and then group all the regions that are houses etc but I have millions of premises, so I am worried about the performance of such an implementation. What do you think? Any ideas?

Comment: @GBG Sorry, forgot to mention that I am implementing this in Python. The density layer you mention is quite similar to the grid solution that I have working am i right? Is there a difference that I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works